# Kusto Query to transform the results in another table

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have in Azure Data Explorer a table like this:

| OrderNo | InitDate | EndDate | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | 2021/06/23 00:15 | 2021/06/23 00:19 | 5 |
| 00002 | 2021/06/23 00:35 | 2021/06/23 00:43 | 8 |

How I can get with a Kusto query the table with this information:

| OrderNo | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | 2021/06/23 00:15 | 0 |
| 00001 | 2021/06/23 00:19 | 5 |
| 00002 | 2021/06/23 00:35 | 5 |
| 00002 | 2021/06/23 00:43 | 13 |

I need get foreach InitDate and EndDate a row.

In the value I need:

- If is the row representing the InitDate, 0 or the previous value.
- If is the row representing the EndDate, the previous value plus their value.

How I can achieve this with Kusto in Azure Data Explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like the below work for you?

```
datatable(OrderNo:string, InitDate:datetime, EndDate:datetime, Value:long)
[
    "00001", datetime(2021-06-23 00:15), datetime(2021-06-23 00:19), 5, 
    "00002", datetime(2021-06-23 00:35), datetime(2021-06-23 00:43), 8
]
| order by InitDate asc 
| extend EndValue = row_cumsum(Value) | extend InitValue = iff(isnull(prev(EndValue)), 0, prev(EndValue))
| extend Date = pack_array(InitDate, EndDate), Value = pack_array(InitValue, EndValue)
| mv-expand Date to typeof(datetime), Value to typeof(long)
| project OrderNo, Date, Value
```

[image]

Comment: Awsome! Thank you very much!